Is there no UnityLink package in Mathematica 14?
Is there no UnityLink package in Mathematica 14? I can't get it.
Needs["UnityLink`"]

Needs::nocont: Context UnityLink` was not created when Needs was evaluated.

Have you tried to PacletFind it? There's a chance they don't load it on all systems by default anymore

I installed the Unit Hub and confirmed that it exists as PacletFind["UnityLink"]. However, I couldn't get it to Needes.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with my installation (V 14.0.0), since I don't have Unity installed. First[PacletFind["UnityLink"]]["Location"] will return the paclet location, looking into it, there is one file called UnityLink.m which first calls PacletManager`Package`getPacletWithProgress which internally seems to be a wrapper on PacletInstall, then after calling that function it will get into a block to execute Get["UnityLink`"], hence the RecursionLimit.

It appears the installing function just returns the same paclet object with 0.0.1 Version as PacletFind["UnityLink"].

The empty result from PacletFindRemote indicates that UnityLink is no longer available on the public servers.
PacletSiteUpdate[PacletSites[ ]];
PacletFindRemote["Unity*"]
Out[ ] := { }
